# Laravel inRandomOrder repeat twice with pagination

Tags: php, laravel

I have the code:

```
$products = Product::whereIn('id_principal_category', $array)->inRandomOrder()->paginate(6);
```

It sometimes shows me a repeated record.

I have read that I must use whereNotIn, the problem is that it can work if it just one time... but how can i do that if does it have a paginator? because i dont know which the repeated records are and i cant use whereNotIn.. so my question is how can I do that inRandomOrder does not show a repeated record with paginator?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See if `unique()` method helps.

```
$products = Product::whereIn('id_principal_category', $array)->unique()->inRandomOrder()->paginate(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use random ordering with pagination ,mysql cannot  track the rows for each visitor .
I quoted those lines from [Chris Henry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10730527/2570425)

> Solution 1
>
> Pick from a number of existing columns that already indexed for being sorted on. This can include created on, modified timestamps.
>
> Solution 2
>
> You could have an additional column that stores a random number for sorting. It should be indexed, obviously. Periodically, run the following query;
>
> ```
> UPDATE table SET rand_col = RAND();
> ```