# Nodejs & Mongo pagination random order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, random, mongoose, pagination

I am running an iOS app where I display a list of users that are currently online.
I have an API endpoint where I return 10 (or N) users randomly, so that you can keep scrolling and always see new users. Therefore I want to make sure I dont return a user that I already returned before.
I cannot use a cursor or a normal pagination as the users have to be returned randomly.

I tried 2 things, but I am sure there is a better way:

- At first what I did was sending in the parameters of the request the IDs of the user that were already seen.
  ex: 
  But if the user keeps scrolling and has gone through 200 profiles then the list is long and it doesnt look clean.
- Then, in the database, I tried adding a field to each users "online_profiles_already_sent" where i would store an array of the IDs that were already sent to the user (I am using MongoDB)

I can't figure out how to do it in a better/cleaner way

EDIT:
I found a way to do it with MySQL, using RAND(seed)
but I can't figure out if there is a way to do the same thing with Mongo
[PHP MySQL pagination with random ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729633/php-mysql-pagination-with-random-ordering)

Thank you :)

Comment: I think better is keep already requested users in your local data inside app - if you're showing different users for every client or inside session/cookie data. Or if you are returning one list for all clients - then just keep the list on your server part - you can create temp file or shared list, etc.

Comment: Hi @ByteMaster, thanks for your answer but I have several thousand users at once on the app and I don't think keeping it in memory would be the best. Thats why I tried keeping it in the database, but I am sure there must be a better solution.
I found something using MySQL with RAND and a seed, but I can't figure out how to do it with Mongo

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way that you will be able to guarentee that users see **unique** users every time is to store the list of users that have already been seen.  Even in the `RAND` example that you linked to, there is a possibility of intersection with a previous user list because `RAND` won't necessarily exclude previously returned users.

---

### Random Sampling

If you do want to go with random sampling, consider [Random record from MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2824157/691711) which suggests using an an [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) and the [`$sample`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) operator.  The implementation would look something like this:

```
const {
    MongoClient
} = require("mongodb");

const
    DB_NAME = "weather",
    COLLECTION_NAME = "readings",
    MONGO_DOMAIN = "localhost",
    MONGO_PORT = "32768",
    MONGO_URL = `mongodb://${MONGO_DOMAIN}:${MONGO_PORT}`;

(async function () {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL),
        db = await client.db(DB_NAME),
        collection = await db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME);

    const randomDocs = await collection
        .aggregate([{
            $sample: {
                size: 5
            }
        }])
        .map(doc => {
            return {
                id: doc._id,
                temperature: doc.main.temp
            }
        });

    randomDocs.forEach(doc => console.log(`ID: ${doc.id} | Temperature: ${doc.temperature}`));
    client.close();
}());
```

---

### Cache of Previous Users

If you go with maintaining a list of previously viewed users, you could write an implementation using the `$nin` filter and store the `_id` of previously viewed users.

Here is an example using a weather database that I have returning entries 5 at a time until all have been printed:

```
const {
    MongoClient
} = require("mongodb");

const
    DB_NAME = "weather",
    COLLECTION_NAME = "readings",
    MONGO_DOMAIN = "localhost",
    MONGO_PORT = "32768",
    MONGO_URL = `mongodb://${MONGO_DOMAIN}:${MONGO_PORT}`;

(async function () {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL),
        db = await client.db(DB_NAME),
        collection = await db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME);

    let previousEntries = [], // Track ids of things we have seen
        empty = false;

    while (!empty) {
        const findFilter = {};
        if (previousEntries.length) {
            findFilter._id = {
                $nin: previousEntries
            }
        }

        // Get items 5 at a time
        const docs = await collection
            .find(findFilter, {
                limit: 5,
                projection: {
                    main: 1
                }
            })
            .map(doc => {
                return {
                    id: doc._id,
                    temperature: doc.main.temp
                }
            })
            .toArray();

        // Keep track of already seen items
        previousEntries = previousEntries.concat(docs.map(doc => doc.id));

        // Are we still getting items?
        console.log(docs.length);
        empty = !docs.length;

        // Print out the docs
        docs.forEach(doc => console.log(`ID: ${doc.id} | Temperature: ${doc.temperature}`));
    }
    client.close();
}());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I guess I'll go with something like that. Only difference is I'll probably store "previousEntries" in the database, on the user's model, so i'll have to query twice, because I dont wanna store it in memory

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue and can suggest an alternate solution.

*TL;DR: Grab all Object ID of the collections on first landing, randomized using NodeJS and  used it later on.*

- Disadvantage: slow first landing if have million of records
- Advantage: subsequent execution is probably quicker than the other solution

---

Let's get to the detail explain :)

For better explain, I will make the following assumption

### Assumption:

1. Assume programming language used NodeJS

   - Solution works for other programming language as well
2. Assume you have **4 total objects** in yor collections
3. Assume **pagination limit is 2**

## Steps:

### On first execution:

1. **Grab all Object Ids**

*Note: I do have considered performance, this execution takes spit seconds for 10,000 size collections. If you are solving a million record issue then maybe used some form of partition logic first / used the other solution listed*

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').find({}, {_id:1}).map(function(item){ return item._id; });
```

OR

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').find({}, {_id:1}).map(function(item){ return item._id.valueOf(); });
```

Result:

```
ObjectId("FirstObjectID"),
ObjectId("SecondObjectID"),
ObjectId("ThirdObjectID"),
ObjectId("ForthObjectID"),
```

2. **Randomized the array retrive using NodeJS**

Result:

```
ObjectId("ThirdObjectID"),
ObjectId("SecondObjectID"),
ObjectId("ForthObjectID"),
ObjectId("FirstObjectID"),
```

3. **Stored this randomized array:**

- If this is a Server side script that randomized pagination for each user, consider storing in **Cookie / Session**

  - I **suggest Cookie** (with timeout expired linked to browser close) for scaling purpose

### On each retrieval:

1. Retrieve the stored array
2. Grab the pagination item, (e.g. first 2 items)
3. Find the objects for those item using find $in

.

```
db.getCollection('my_collection')
    .find({"_id" : {"$in" : [ObjectId("ThirdObjectID"), ObjectId("SecondObjectID")]}});
```

4. Using NodeJS, sort the retrieved object based on the retrived pagination item

There you go! A randomized MongoDB query for pagination :)

Comment: Revisiting the answer, storing object id in cookie might be insecure, probably storing them in session is better.